# Eclipse and external jars

Tags: eclipse, jar

I've been working on a project on eclipse, I am trying to add an external jar but when I use classes from this jar its not recognizing them and cant build anything. The same jar file I used it before on a previous project and it worked fine, but now, on this new project its not working, this is on a Mac. I tried making a new project on a Windows and added the external jar and worked fine too. In an attempt to maybe make it work I removed the reference to the external jar from the previous project but still not working. I read questions relating to mine here which most of them said to check the checkbox in order and export and adding my jar file to a library and but none of them worked. Why is it not working for my second project?

EDIT: I tried the following to add the jar file, add external archives from the build path of the project, I tried adding a user library and adding the jar file to it

Comment: I tried to add them with adding external jar archives from build path and by adding a user library and adding the jar to it. For the first project that worked fine I added it with the adding external archives from build path

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if you add correct jar path, as well as, jar is readable.